# Solving recurrence relation with square root by reduction

Tags: recurrence-relation

This question has already been asked, but I still cannot understand how the substitution makes sense in the recurrence equation $$T(n)=2T(\sqrt{n})+1$$

Following the logic:

1. Substitute $n$ for $2^m$. This yields the equation:

$$
T(2^m)=2T(\sqrt{2^m})+1=2T(2^{m/2})+1 \\
\text{where } n = 2^m,\ m=\log_2 n
$$
Great, this makes sense because we can substitute $n$ back in for $2^m$ and then we get the original equation.

2. Now we introduce a new function $S(m)$ and we're going to say $S(m)$ = $T(2^m)$.
3. I don't believe this implies $m=2^m$, because that would not make sense. So we're saying we're defining a new function $S$ that takes parameter $m$ and simply returns the function $T$ with parameter $2^m$:
   $$S(m) \rightarrow T(2^m)=2T(\sqrt{2^m})+1=2T(2^{m/2})+1 $$
4. Fine, but since the $m$ is $S$ has no mathematical relationship to the $m$ in $T$, I'm going to rename $S(m)$ to be $S(x)$ to avoid confusion, so:
   $$S(x) \rightarrow T(2^m)=2T(\sqrt{2^m})+1=2T(2^{m/2})+1 $$
5. Now if we pass $x/2$ into $S$, we get:
   $$
   S(x/2) \rightarrow T(2^{x/2})=2T(\sqrt{2^{x/2}})+1=2T(2^{{x/2}/2})+1=2T(2^{x/4})+1 \\
   $$
6. Using the master theorem for $S(x/2)$, we get $O(\log x)$. However, since we have no equivalence of $x$ and $n$, then how do we substitute back to get $n$?

---

So this leads me to believe there must be some mathematical relationship between $S(m)$ and $T(2^m)$. If $2^m$ is substituted for $m$, I'm going to replace $x$ with $m$ again, because it doesn't make sense to me to use the same variable in a substitution and make it confusing.

1. Therefore:
   $$
   S(x) = T(2^m)=2T(\sqrt{2^m})+1=2T(2^{m/2})+1 \\
   S(x/2) = T(2^{x/2})=2T(\sqrt{2^{x/2}})+1=2T(2^{{x/2}/2})+1=2T(2^{x/4})+1 \\
   \text{where } x=2^m
   $$
2. Now my problem with this is:
   If $x=2^m$, $m=\log x$, $m$ also equals $\log n$, therefore $\log x=\log n$, $n=x$.

If $x=n$ then $S(x/2)=\dots=2T(2^{n/4})+1$.

3.
The master theorem says $S(x/2) = \Theta(log_2(x))$.

Now $x=n$, so $\Theta(\log_2 x)=\Theta(\log_2 n)$,
which is the right answer for $T(n)$. However:
$$
2T(2^{n/4})+1 \neq 2T(\sqrt{n})+1.
$$
So, how can we say that the Big O of $S(x/2)$ is equivalent to the Big O of $T(n)$?

---

I obviously know I'm wrong. But the correct answer to this problem makes the math seem "hacky" and arbitrary. I can't seem to grasp how the logic maintains its equivalence?

Can someone help me understand how my thinking is wrong? If so, is there anyway to explain this without using $S(m)=T(2^m)$ because in either case I don't understand what this actually means.

Comment: Step 4 is where you go wrong. The $m$ in $S(m)$ is the same $m$ as in $T(2^m)$ in fact you have defined that $S(m) := T(2^m)$. In Step 4 you should write something like:
$S(m) = T(2^m) = 2T(2^{m/2}) + 1 = 2S(m/2)+1$. Notice that you can solve
$S(m) =  2S(m/2)+1$ for O(S(m)) and then since $m = log(n)$: $S(T(n))=O(S(\log n))$

Comment: The mathematical relationship between $S(m)$ and $T(2^m)$ is: $S(m) = T(2^m)$.

Comment: Another mathematical relationship, which is quite useful here, is: $T(n) = S(\log_2 n)$.

Comment: you could simply say that T could be expressed as a fn. of *m* instead of as function of *n* where *m=logn*; ie *T(s(m))=2T(s(m/2))+1* & *s(m)= 2^m* . Now you reach the solution *T(s(m))= O(log(s(m)))=O(log(2^m))*, you can substitute n=(2^m) getting *T(n)=O(log n)*

Comment: I’m having trouble understanding how a we can arbitrarily decide S(m)=T(2^m) and how this then yields S(m/2) and then is somehow still equivalent to the original function

Comment: Check the end of my answer.

Comment: Take for instance $T(m)=m^2+1$. Then $S(m)=T(2^m)=(2^m)^2+1=2^{2m}+1$ is a well defined function.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the logical form of the argument.

1. The starting point is a function $T$ defined recursively.

(Comments: (1) Your definition misses a base case; (2) If you think of the input to $T$ as an integer, then $T$ is only defined for integers of the form $2^{2^k}$.)

2. Using $T$, we *define* another function $S$ by $S(m) = T(2^m)$. This function satisfies the recurrence $S(m) = 2S(m/2) + 1$, with base case $S(1) = T(2)$.

(Here we assume that the input to $S$ is an integer; so $S$ is only defined for integers of the form $2^k$.)

3. We find the asymptotic rate of growth of $S(m)$ to be $\Theta(m)$.

(In fact, $S(m)+1 = 2(S(m/2)+1)$, and so $S(m) = m(1 + S(1)) - 1$.)

4. Since $T(n) = S(\log_2 n)$, we conclude that the asymptotic rate of growth of $T(n)$ is $\Theta(\log n)$.

(In fact, $T(2^m) = m(1 + T(2)) - 1$.)

Answer (score 0):

The question is best answered with $n=2^{2^m}$ so that

$$T(2^{2^m})=2T(\sqrt{2^{2^m}})+1=2T(2^{2^{m-1}})+1.$$

This has the functional form

$$S(m)=2S(m-1)+1$$

and it is no big deal to find the solution of the homogeneous recurrence $S_h(m)=c\,2^m$ and a particular solution $S_p(m)=-1$.

Now,

$$S(m)=c\,2^m-1$$ is another way to write

$$T(2^{2^m})=c\,2^m-1$$ or

$$T(n)=c\,\log_2(n)-1.$$

---

As we can check,

$$2c\,(\log_2(\sqrt n)-1)+1=\frac22c\,\log_2(n)-2+1=c\,\log_2(n)-1.$$

---

The flaw in your reasoning is to think that "the $m$ in $S$ has no mathematical relationship to the $m$ in $T$". On the opposite it is the same variable, and $S(m)=T(2^{2^m})$ is an identity, also written $S(\log_2(n))=T(2^n)$ or  $S(\log_2(\log_2(n)))=T(n)$, which does define $S$ uniquely in terms of $T$.